# How can I get the deployed contract's address from a ContractContainer object in Brownie?

Tags: ether, python, brownie

I want to chain contract deployment, where the second contract gets as a parameter the address of the first using `Brownie`:

```py
from brownie import ContractA, ContractB , accounts

def main():
    acct = accounts[0]
    ContractA.deploy({'from': acct})
    ContractB.deploy(ContractA.address, {'from': acct})
```

With `web3` and `Truffle`, the deployed contract instance can be imported and we get its address with `.address`. However, brownie `CountractContainer` are function objects and I can't understand how to get the deployed address.

Comment: Were you trying to achieve this on the `ganache` blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code with some changes that should work.

```
from brownie import ContractA, ContractB , accounts

def main():
    acct = accounts[0]
    container = ContractA.deploy({'from': acct})
    ContractB.deploy(container.address, {'from': acct})
```